# cobertura code coverage and report generation only with class files is possible?

Tags: java, ant, cobertura

I am trying to use the cobertura- ant for code coverage. Here can i use the class files directly for instrumentation and use a DE compiler to get the java files for report generation? will it give the coverage correctly?
Since i have only the class files not the java files.
Please provide your valuable inputs on this.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "trying to use", do you mean that you have tried it and are not getting the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it.  Since the report is basically an annotated listing of the code, I would think the `cobertura-report` task needs to have the source code.

Any way, what good is the report if you don't have the source code?